# A shorter way to set up links in Wordpress posts?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

It bugs me that every time I add a link in the content area of a Wordpress page or post, I have to type the entire `<a href="http://mywebsite.com/images/myimage.jpg">` text as opposed to quick formats available in php or the css file, such as `<a href="url(images/myimage.jpg)">`.

Is writing out the entire domain every time the only way to set the link up, or am I missing out on a shortcut?

Comment: Why don't you use the media library?

Comment: I'm just talking about a general rule for links in content. I'm setting up a site and linking to pages, posts, contact page, etc.

Comment: Well, if you use the media library it's just a few mouseclicks, no need to type any path at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides using the "Add Media" button above the text entry, there is no default way to enter that little info. You can register some short code so you could write it like `[img src="myimage.jpg"]` in your text editor.

functions.php

```
function img_func( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'src' => 'something'
    ), $atts ) );
    $route = 'http://mywebsite.com/images/'.$src;
    return $route;
}
add_shortcode( 'img', 'img_func' );
```